# How to split dataframes with multiple categories using str.contains in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this,

```
id   col1
1    apple, peach
2    apple, banana
3    melon, peach
4    berry, apple, peach
5    melon, banana
```

This table has 5 categories in `col1`.

I know how to select each category using str.contains().

```
df_apple = df[df['col1'].str.contains("apple")]
df_peach = df[df['col1'].str.contains("peach")]
df_melon = df[df['col1'].str.contains("melon")]
df_berry = df[df['col1'].str.contains("berry")]
df_banana = df[df['col1'].str.contains("banana")]
```

How can I generate 5 dataframes in one time using some pandas function?
So my outputs are 5 dataframes named `df_apple, df_peach, df_melon, df_berry, df_banana`.

And saved them into 5 different csv files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd `explode` the column an find unique `id`

```
d = df.set_index('id').col1
e = d.str.split(', ').explode()

r = {k: d.loc[v] for k, v in e.index.groupby(e).items()}

r['apple']

id
1           apple, peach
2          apple, banana
4    berry, apple, peach
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

---

Or to dump to csv

```
d = df.set_index('id').col1
e = d.str.split(', ').explode()

for k, v in e.index.groupby(e).items():
    d.loc[v].to_frame().to_csv(f"{k}.csv")
```

Then

```
pd.read_csv('apple.csv')

   id                 col1
0   1         apple, peach
1   2        apple, banana
2   4  berry, apple, peach
```

---

For Pandas versions < `0.25`

```
def explode(s):
    return pd.Series(np.concatenate(s.to_numpy()), s.index.repeat(s.str.len()))

d = df.set_index('id').col1
e = d.str.split(', ').pipe(explode)
```

And see [this post by @MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449726/2336654)

Comment: It gave me an error.`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'`. So confused I checked the doc that `explode` should be a method applied on Series. Does it because I have multiple columns rather than my sample dataframe with only 2 columns?

Comment: you are using an older version of pandas.  `explode` came out in version 0.25

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to store them in a dict :

`dfdict = {fruit:df[df['col1'].str.contains(fruit)] for fruit in ['apple', 'peach', 'melon', 'berry', 'banana']}`

```
for k,v in dfdict.items():
    v.to_csv('df'+k+'.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Benoit. So how can I save them into multiple csv files? I know these 'key' should be iterated.

Comment: I added it to my answer